# Using mysql but can't insert to database

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I have a db named lablab with a table named table so my program is a registration when registered it will save userName, fullName, birthDay, password and age in the database. My database has columns of fullName, userName, passWord, birthDay and age. My program runs but it can't insert to database.

Here is my mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="hello.model" table="table" schema="lablab">
<id name="id" column="ID"  type="int">
<generator class="native"/>
</id>
<property name="fullName" column="fullName" type="string"/>
<property name="userName" column="userName" type="string"/>
<property name="passWord" column="passWord" type="string"/>
<property name="birthDay" column="birthDay" type="string"/>
<property name="age" column="age" type="int"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is my cfg.xml

```
  <hibernate-configuration>

  <session-factory>

  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>

  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>

  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

  <property 
  name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lablab</property>

  <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>

  </session-factory>

  </hibernate-configuration>
```

here is my java class

```
  package hello;

 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
 import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
 import org.hibernate.Session;
 import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
 import org.hibernate.Transaction;
  import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
  import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class model extends ActionSupport{
private String fullName, passWord, userName, birthDay, yearX, userLogin, passLogin;
private int age, year, yearN;
private static SessionFactory factory;

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public String getPassWord() {
    return passWord;
}

public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
    this.passWord = passWord;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getBirthDay() {
    return birthDay;
}

public void setBirthDay(String birthDay) {
    this.birthDay = birthDay;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getUserLogin() {
    return userLogin;
}

public void setUserLogin(String userLogin) {
    this.userLogin = userLogin;
}

public String getPassLogin() {
    return passLogin;
}

public void setPassLogin(String passLogin) {
    this.passLogin = passLogin;
}

public String register() throws Exception {
    try
      { 
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
        applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
      }
      catch (HibernateException ex)
      { 
         System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
      }
    addUser(fullName, userName, passWord, birthDay, age);
    String success ="success";
    return success;
 }

private Integer addUser(String fullName, String userName, String passWord, String birthDay, int age) {
Session session = factory.openSession();
  Transaction tx = null;
  Integer uID = null;
  try{
     tx = session.beginTransaction();
     User item = new User(fullName, userName, passWord, birthDay, age) {};
     uID = (Integer) session.save(item); 
     tx.commit();
  }catch (HibernateException e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     e.printStackTrace(); 
  }finally {
     session.close(); 
  }
  return uID;
}
```

}

And here is my user class

```
class User {

private String fullName, userName, passWord, birthDay;
private int age;
public User(){}


public User(String fullName, String userName, String passWord, String birthDay, int age){
this.fullName = fullName;
this.userName = userName;
this.passWord = passWord;
this.birthDay = birthDay;
this.age = age;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassWord() {
    return passWord;
}

public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
    this.passWord = passWord;
}

public String getBirthDay() {
    return birthDay;
}

public void setBirthDay(String birthDay) {
    this.birthDay = birthDay;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

Comment: Where is your ``main``? Is there an exception? Whats stopping you from debugging?

Comment: *My program runs but it can't insert to database* means?

Comment: Why can't it?  Any error?  Have you tried stepping through the INSERTs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate 5 you should create the `SessionFactory` by this way:

```
factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

This is an incorrect way:

```
 Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
 StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
 applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
 factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
```